# How to sort datemonthyear by reverse chronological order using Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have folder named like 29Jun2011,12Aug2013,31Jan2013,08Aug1985. I have to sort out reverse chronological order using Python script. And I have to store a latest one in a variable and print it.

Comment: That's your task, now what is your question?

Comment: Have a look at [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) module and `sorted` function.

Comment: The python datetime module is needlessly confusing, and a beginner certainly can't navigate their way around it.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, Can you please explain how a computer programming question is 'off-topic' on SO?  Why would you ever vote to silence a question and prevent other people from answering?  Is free speech and the free flow of ideas just a complete affront to you?  Why is it that if you don't like a question, you aren't able to just go read another question?

Comment: @7stud **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.**

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime as dt

date_strs = [
    "29Jun2011",
    "08Aug1985",
    "12Aug2013",
]

my_format = "%d%b%Y"

datetime_objs = []

for date_str in date_strs:
    my_datetime = dt.datetime.strptime(date_str, my_format)
    datetime_objs.append(my_datetime)

print datetime_objs
datetime_objs.sort(reverse=True)
print datetime_objs
print datetime_objs[0].strftime("%B %d, %Y")


--output:--
[datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1985, 8, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 12, 0, 0)]
[datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1985, 8, 8, 0, 0)]
August 12, 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the names of the folders then please use ISO-8601 date formats, that is `YYYY-MM-DD`; you can sort them using standard ASCII collation ;)

If that is not possible, you can sort with

```
import time

def sortkey(s):
    return time.strptime(s, '%d%b%Y')

names = sorted(unsorted_names, key=sortkey)
```

However, if you need ONLY the latest, then you ONLY need the maximum value:

```
def sortkey(s):
    return time.strptime(s, '%d%b%Y')

date, filename = max((sortkey(i), i) for i in unsorted_names)
print date, filename
```

This is much faster. Generally if your problem is "find the maximum", you do not want to use sort; if only maximum value is required, use the `max()` function; if n values are required, use the `heapq.nlargest`

Comment: No need to use `mktime` here or negate the value, just use `time.strptime` and supply `reverse=True` to `sorted`

Comment: True, but the sort key is better the smaller it is.

Comment: The overhead of using `mktime` which has to do the maths to calculate a number based epoch using the elements of the objects returned by `strptime` is significantly more overhead than just letting the objects order theirselves naturally...

Comment: And, if one was really concerned all about efficiency, you'd use `first, = heapq.nlargest(1, unsorted_names, key=lambda L: time.strptime(L, '%d%b%Y))` and let the internals of heapq do the work

Comment: Indeed, that is the right approach, I just read this as "I must sort, and also I must take the latest one in a variable.